# Visibility of report field dependent on the value of another field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I  have two columns one [CUS SKU], the other [UPC].
I have 2 specific id's 1234, 1233 and many others but only care if these two show up.

My problem-

If either of these two show up on both columns I only want to display one column and hide the other.

If another id is displayed in both columns display both.

If  another id shows up on either column and neither of the two important ids are shown then display in either of the columns.

also the two important id's will sometimes have 0 or 00 in front, how do i accommodate for that in there as well.

this is what i tried in each column but had no luck, it was displaying the same.

```
=IIF (Fields!CUS_SKU.Value = ("1234") or Fields!CUS_SKU.Value = ("1233")  and Fields!UPC.Value = ("1234") or Fields!UPC.Value = ("1233"), True, False)
```

and

```
=IIF (Fields!CUS_SKU.Value <> ("1234") or Fields!CUS_SKU.Value <> ("1233")  and Fields!UPC.Value = ("1234") or Fields!UPC.Value = ("1233"), False, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When mixing AND and OR in a condition, you need to use parens carefully.   Try this:

```
=IIF ((Fields!CUS_SKU.Value = ("1234") or Fields!CUS_SKU.Value = ("1233"))  and (Fields!UPC.Value = ("1234") or Fields!UPC.Value = ("1233")), True, False)
```